# Unexpected nan behaviour when summing a numpy array full of nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, nan

This is an interesting topic given it could lead to unexpected results in code. Suppose I had an array as follows;

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan])
```

`np.nanmean(X)` rightly returns a warning that the averaging slice is empty and returns nan. However, when doing a summation of the array, `np.nansum(X)`, it returns `0.0`. Now while mathematically true (the sum of nothing is 0), the result expected to be returned might be np.nan.

For an example, I have a function where if a file of ice data doesn't exist, it will create an empty array of nans (180x360 points with each point representing a lat/lon degree). This array is then passed to a function which sums over the array to find out the total amount of ice in the array. If the expected value is 9-10 million km2, and nansum is returning 0, this can be misleading. This is especially difficult if ice extents are around 0 anyway.
In the plot below this is clearly a missing data file leading to a ice sum of 0.0, but not all cases are so clear.

[image]

I've seen this discussed on development websites, and want to know why there isn't an kwarg option for `np.nansum()` to return np.nan if required, and B, is there a function which returns True/False if the entire matrix is full of nan?

Comment: From the [documentation of `np.nansum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html): "Return the sum of array elements over a given axis treating Not a Numbers (NaNs) as zero."... I'd say it returning `0.0` is exactly the expected behaviour. Note that this changed in `numpy` 1.8 (again from the docs: "In NumPy versions <= 1.8.0 Nan is returned for slices that are all-NaN or empty. In later versions zero is returned.")

Comment: 0.0 is correct but can cause issues in certain cases when handling nan's. Clearly if it numpy got changed at a later time it isn't such an intuitive result for nansum.

Comment: older numpy versions have the behavior you expect

Comment: See [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2013-July/067092.html) for the original discussion leading to the change.

Comment: You can't really describe the documented behaviour as unexpected. If you think that's the wrong behaviour, it's maybe a bug in numpy (evidently not in this case, as the behaviour was already discussed and changed by that community), not an SO question. We can't really answer why there isn't an alternative implementation or flag, either; that's one for the actual maintainers. And please **don't put meta content in questions**.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate that, I am relatively new to stack overflow, and appreciate the help. I don't appreciate the neg'ing and hostile reaction I get for asking something I thought was interesting. It does nothing to encourage people to post questions on this site

Comment: You haven't had *"neg'ing and hostile reaction"*. You've had constructive comments, an answer and a handful of downvotes. Also note this is about the *question*, not *you*.

Comment: I count neg'ing as down-voting, just my interpretation! The hostile comment was a result of other comments from others which they have since deleted. Yes, I'm aware this is in response to the question, I'm not taking it personally!

Answer (score 9):

[Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html):

> In NumPy versions <= 1.8.0 Nan is returned for slices that are all-NaN
>   or empty. In later versions zero is returned.

Workaround:

```
def nansumwrapper(a, **kwargs):
    if np.isnan(a).all():
        return np.nan
    else:
        return np.nansum(a, **kwargs)

a = np.array([np.nan, np.nan])
b = np.array([np.nan, 1., 2.])


nansumwrapper(a)
# nan

nansumwrapper(b)
# 3.0
```

You can pass kwargs to `np.nansum()`:

```
c = np.arange(12, dtype=np.float_).reshape(4,3)
c[2:4, 1] = np.nan

nansumwrapper(c, axis=1)
# array([  3.,  12.,  14.,  20.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving of the Brad Solomon's workaround. Passing `**kwargs` to `all()` allows partial nan-tagging.

```
def nansumwrapper(a, **kwargs):
    mx = np.isnan(a).all(**kwargs)
    res = np.nansum(a, **kwargs)
    res[mx] = np.nan
    return res
```